# Put “| LimitTo” in Angular.js using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I am new in Angular.js
I am currently in a dropdown showing a list of cities in Colombia and the United States countries.

I'm using "ng-option". I want in the dropdown cities only 10 characters is limited. and if so to appear ellipsis (...). 
I just want this to appear in the dropdown, not the value of if it did with "ng-repeat" I would more or less so.

```
<option ng-repeat='state in countries' value='{{state.id}}'>  {{state.dep | LimitTo: 10}} {{state.dep.length> 10? '...' ''}} </option>
```

how I can do the same but with ng-option?

http://plnkr.co/edit/qGwqrlSbDrmuvpY1dI7I?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a function on the scope

```
$scope.getLimitedWord = function(word, size){
  if(word.length <= size){
    return word;
  } else {
    return word.substr(0,10) + '...';
  }
}
```

And using it

```
<select id="state" 
    ng-model="selectedState" 
    ng-options="state.id as getLimitedWord(state.dep,10) for state in ((countries | filter:{'id':selectedCountry})[0].states) track by state.id">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/NJRlvem5jnVVMvpE9Etf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter which will put a limit character to an array object's certain property.

```
/**
  * @name limitToChar
  * 
  * @description Creates a new array with making object's certain property characters limited.
  * 
  * @param input - source array
  * @param {string} prop - property in the array object which will be limit to certain characters
  * @param {number} limit - no of characters to be limited
  * 
  * @returns a new array.
  */
 Aplic.filter('limitToChar', function() {
   return function(input, prop, limit) {
     if(input) {
       var newArray = angular.copy(input);
       limit = limit || 10;
       for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
         if(newArray[i][prop] && newArray[i][prop].length > limit) {
          newArray[i][prop] = newArray[i][prop].substring(0, limit) + '...';
         }
       }
       return newArray;
     }
   }
 })
```

And in the `ng-options` of `states`, apply the filter:

> limitToChar:'dep':10

```
ng-options="state.id as state.dep for state in (((countries | filter:{'id':selectedCountry})[0].states) | limitToChar:'dep':10) track by state.id"
```

The `limitToChar` filter creates a new array, filters it objects property(passed property) with certain characters(limit) and returns the new array. The default is 10 for limit. So, if you don't pass limit, 10 will be the character count.

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/IEwsCh4DlT4YYnLGKobb?p=preview)