# selectpicker is not working while adding function in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Here I am trying to set limit of drop down list contents by 60 characters by calling a function in ng-options. its work but while I am selecting or choosing any item from drop down its not showing or piking the item in drop down you see in image.

here I am selecting the item from drop down.

[image]

after selecting its not showing in drop down here is image.

[image]

can any buddy tell me what I am doing wrong in my code!!

here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 nopadding select-job">
   <label for="selectJob" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 nopadding"> Select Job </label>

<select id="selectJob" name="selectJob" class="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start" ng-model="formInfo.selectedJob" ng-options="job.jobTitle as getLimitedWord(job.jobTitle,60) for job in companyJob track by job.jobTitle">
  <option value="">Select Your Option</option>                                                                                
</select>

 <button class="btn btn-labeled btn-info btn-reload pull-right" ng-disabled="formInfo.selectedJob == undefined || formInfo.selectedJob == null || !formInfo.selectTechnology"
                            data-ng-click="uploadJobDescription()">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <span class="small-left-margin">Load Job</span>
                            </button>
                    </div>
```

here is my function where i am setting the size of drop down items which are showing in image.

```
$scope.getLimitedWord = function(word, size) {
      if(word.length <= size){
        return word;
      } else {
        return word.substr(0,60) + '...';
      }
    };
```

here is companyJob array from controller:

```
$scope.getCompanyDetails = function (company) {
      uploadService.getCompanyDetail(company)
        .then(function (data) {
          $scope.company = data.CompanyDetail;
          $scope.companyJob = data.CompanyDetail.jobDescriptions;

        },
```

actually i am following this [link code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383284/put-limitto-in-angular-js-using-ng-options) from here you check it.
if someone know whats wrong i am doing please correct it.Thank you.

Comment: First make sure the return statement in your `getLimitedWord` function returns something. Are there any console errors? Also can you post the `companyJob ` array?

Comment: @gilango no there is no console errors,

Comment: @gilango please see I have updated my question with companyJob array.

Comment: I want to see the sample JSON structure of the `companyJob` array. Something like  $scope.countries =[
   {
     'id': '1',
      'name': "Colombia"
   }];

Comment: actually right now i am unable to send you that json structure tomorrow  i will update you.bcoz i cant access that json right now,and thank you for your reply.